# Python numpy fill 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have raw data and that has been converted to RGB values. Those values are in a list like [R, G, B]. So essentially I have [[R,G,B],...,[R,G,B]]. Now I want to make a matrix by width*height*3.

```
rgb_list = []

for i in range(0, channel_bytes):
    r = channel_1.__getitem__(i)
    g = channel_2.__getitem__(i)
    b = channel_3.__getitem__(i)
    rgb_list.append([r, g, b])

image_matrix = np.array(rgb_list)
image_matrix.reshape(image_height, image_width, 3)
print(image_matrix)
```

Still gives me the following output:

```
[[22 21 13]
 [30 23 23]
 [19 23 16]
 ..., 
 [17 17 18]
 [18 17 10]
 [16 17 18]]
```

But it should be

```
[[[22, 21, 13]],
 [[30, 23, 23]],
 ...,
[[16, 17, 18]]]
```

Comment: You just want to add a dimension to your current output?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out the moment I posted it! Always happens to me for some reason. I had to write: image_matrix = image_matrix.reshape(x, y, z)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

L = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]])
L.reshape(1, 6, 3)

# Output:
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]]])
```

No clue why you want to do that thou...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

It reshaped the matrix but did not save the changes. It should be:

image_matrix = image_matrix.reshape(image_height, image_width, 3)